# press the button that I created it crashes the app

Tags: android

I was following a tutorial on how to start, and stuff. I did exactly the same but for some reason when I press the button that I created it crashes the app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.example.pokemoninfo.PokemonKnop"></activity>
</application>
```

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    PokemonKnop.setOnClickListener {
        d("dani", "Pressed this button")
        startActivity(Intent(this, PokemonKnop::class.java))
    }

}
}

class PokemonKnop : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(activity_pokemon_knop)
}
}
```

Comment: Attaching logs from `LogCat` will help. Edit your question pasting the exceptions or errors from logs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively new to using Android Studio as well.  AS will provide feedback on the errors, but it can be somewhat cryptic, and sometimes misleading, imo.
You need to get information on the error or issue that's causing it to crash. To get that info, try running your app using the "Debug App" option, by clicking on the icon that looks somewhat like a green bug on the top menu bar of Android Studio.  I've circled it in the attached image.

[image]

Keep your device connected, and when you press the button and it crashes, you should get some information about the problem in the Debug window at the bottom.